# Is there a way to use custom fonts in a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, fonts

Well basically I'm finishing school in mid December so I'm just brushing up my resume and I'm wondering if there's a way to use custom fonts (in this case Calibri and Cambria) in a PDF file and make them render correctly on all computers.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I'm using MS Word 2007, but am open to suggestions

Answer (score 12):

PDFs don't store text and fonts like other documents, they actually convert the font to vectors, that way no matter what font you use, the document displays exactly as expected.  This is why searching for text inside the PDF is such a problem for 3rd party PDF Readers and why even Adobe themselves use to distribute 2 versions of Acrobat (one with text search, one without).

Another thing to keep in mind is, PDF isn't pixel exact, it's ratio exact.  PDF readers generally do not use a 100% zoom level, instead most people read them at "fit to screen" or "fit to page".  I point this out because I'm guessing the reason you are trying to use those new Vista/Office 2007 fonts is because of their LCD subpixel support (improves readability on LCD screens).  This feature will not translate into the PDF, since the letter becomes a vector, subpixel information is lost, and even if it wasn't, becomes useless because the vector will be sized to something other than you intended at view time.

Comment: Yes fonts are represented by vectors, but the displayed text in a PDF is still represented by a particular character set and a stream of values representing the fonts, i.e. in an uncompressed PDF stream, assuming traditional character set, you will see an 'A' is still 65 (0x41).

Comment: Subpixel rendering isn't a feature of any particular fonts, it's a method of display that works on any vector font.

But because it's done by vectors, good PDF viewers would apply subpixel rendering as appropriate.

Comment: The font can still be optimized for subpixel use, but there are some huge assumptions, like the effect only works for particular sizes.  It does make a difference, I the sub pixel optimized fonts from MS do look better.

Comment: I've never seen "3rd party PDF readers" having problems with searching for text *(unless of course you saved the text as an image)*, and I used a lot of them. Various embedded into site readers, a pdf.js project, Evince, Okular… That, coupled with absence of references, and other answers implying there *is* a way to embed a font, makes me doubt the validity of the answer as a whole.

Answer (score 4):

The PDF format is capable of embedding fonts, if the font has been marked embeddable by its creator.  You'll have to check the software that's creating your PDF to see if it has the capability and how to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

theoretically speaking, on technical side, embedding/not embedding ability, regarding the fonts, is settled with a special flag in font file (ttf or opentype or type1)

you can view this special embedding flag with any font **editor** program (I recommend

**FontCreator** (by High-logic)

- http://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator.html

with a free trial fully operative and without limitations

you can also change embedding/not embedding flag, but legally speaking, for the 99% of fonts commercially distributed, this breaks the license of font